# Specific C shifting operations. Have a look and tell me what it is about

Tags: c, stm32

```
SYSCFG->EXTICR[EXTI_PinSourcex >> 0x02] &= 
                                 ~((uint32_t)0x0F) << 
                                (0x04 * (EXTI_PinSourcex & (uint8_t)0x03));

SYSCFG->EXTICR[EXTI_PinSourcex >> 0x02] |= 
                                  (((uint32_t)EXTI_PortSourceGPIOx) << 
                                (0x04 * (EXTI_PinSourcex & (uint8_t)0x03)));
```

This is a piece of code from the STM32F4 board standard library. I understand every single operation but the entire code is really messy. Please accept the challenge and tell me what it is about in a more intuitive way.

And for simplicity, try to explain the situation when `EXTI_PinSourcex` is `0x01`, and the `EXTI_PortSourceGPIOx` is `0x01` as well .

Any comments is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you printed value of `SYSCFG->EXTICR[EXTI_PinSourcex >> 0x02]` it should be `0`. And as you says `EXTI_PinSourcex` = `0x01`, So `SYSCFG->EXTICR[0x01 >> 0x02]`  == `SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]` And I think `SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]` == **Zero** after this expression, just print it.

Comment: This sounds like a job for codegolf.SE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, bitwise operator math.

It's easier to understand if you break it apart into pieces and "unoptimize" some of the language syntax. Let's also make the bigger variable convolutions easier to read:

`SYSCFG->EXTICR[EXTI_PinSourcex >> 0x02] &= 
                                 ~((uint32_t)0x0F) << 
                                (0x04 * (EXTI_PinSourcex & (uint8_t)0x03));`

becomes:

```
#define cfgval_shift_2r   (SYSCFG->EXTICR[EXTI_PinSourcex >> 0x02])
cfgval_shift_2r = (cfgval_shift_2r) & ~((uint32_t)0x0F) << (0x04 * (EXTI_PinSourcex & (uint8_t)0x03));
```

Unraveling some of the constant bitwise math (such as `~((uint32_t)0x0F)`):

```
cfgval_shift_2r = (cfgval_shift_2r) & 0xFFF0 << (0x04 * (EXTI_PinSourcex & 0x03));
```

Now we have something that's a little easier to read.

**`EXTI_PinSourcex` == `0x00`:**

```
// cfgval_shift_2r = SYSCFG->EXTICR[0], because 0 shifted any number of bits is always 0
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = (SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]) & 0xFFF0 << (0x04 * (0 & 0x03));
//                                                  \ == 0           /
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = (SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]) & 0xFFF0;
```

So this takes the value of `SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]` and simply masks the **least-significant byte** off and assigns it back as the value.

**`EXTI_PinSourcex` == `0x01`:**

```
// cfgval_shift_2r = SYSCFG->EXTICR[0], because (0x01 >> 0x02) == 0
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = (SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]) & 0xFFF0 << (0x04 * (0x01 & 0x03));
//                                                \ == 0x04 * 0x01 == 0x04 /
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = (SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]) & 0xFFF0 << 0x04;
```

So this takes the value of `SYSCFG->EXTICR[0]`, masks the **least-significant byte** off, shifts everything to the left by 4 bits, and assigns it back as the value.

You can apply a similar breakdown to the second operation.